# ¿Cómo buscar secuencia ordenada de números más larga en una lista?

Tags: python

Necesito buscar en una lista desordenada la secuencia de números más larga y pasarla a otra lista.

Por ejemplo, si el input es [5, 7, 4, 4, 6, 9, 2, 6], las secuencias ordenadas (de menor a mayor) que hay dentro son: [5, 7], [4, 4, 6, 9] y [2, 6]. Pero la que necesito es la mas larga, asi que el output debería ser [4, 4, 6, 9].

Estoy teniendo problemas para "capturar" las secuencias y que no se me mezclen

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Debes mostrar lo que has intentado, puedes leer [mcve] para que tengas una idea. De lo contrario tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probá de esta manera:

```
arr = [5, 7, 4, 4, 6, 9, 2, 6]
seqs = []
for i, num in enumerate(arr):
  if i==0:
    seq = [num]
  else:
    if num < seq[-1]:
      seqs.append(seq)
      seq = [num]
    else:
      seq.append(num)
  if i+1 == len(arr):
    seqs.append(seq)
print(seqs)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero considera que podrías haberle hecho la tarea a alguien. Eso puede perjudicar su aprendizaje. Además, como funciona esta respuesta? Por que responde la duda del OP?